# CMake could not find Perl

Tags: cmake, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to build mbedcrypto using my own recipe for arm board using Yocto Linux. I am able to download and unpack the source code but during compile of the library , i get the errors

```
| -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
| -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
| -- Detecting C compile features
| -- Detecting C compile features - done
| -- Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing:  PYTHON_EXECUTABLE)
| -- Could NOT find Perl (missing:  PERL_EXECUTABLE)
```

Relevant CMakeLists.txt portion as follows

```
set(CTR_DRBG_128_BIT_KEY_WARNING "${WARNING_BORDER}"
                         "${CTR_DRBG_128_BIT_KEY_WARN_L1}"
                         "${CTR_DRBG_128_BIT_KEY_WARN_L2}"
                         "${CTR_DRBG_128_BIT_KEY_WARN_L3}"
                         "${WARNING_BORDER}")


find_package(PythonInterp)
find_package(Perl)
if(PERL_FOUND)

    # If 128-bit keys are configured for CTR_DRBG, display an appropriate warning
    execute_process(COMMAND ${PERL_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/scripts/config.pl -f ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/mbedtls/config.h get MBEDTLS_CTR_DRBG_USE_128_BIT_KEY
```

The error msg

```
 Found Threads: TRUE
| -- Could NOT find Perl (missing:  PERL_EXECUTABLE)
| CMake Error at tests/CMakeLists.txt:15 (message):
|   Cannot build test suites without Perl
```

comes from the file tests/CMakeLists.txt  which has

```
if(ENABLE_ZLIB_SUPPORT)
    set(libs ${libs} ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES})
endif(ENABLE_ZLIB_SUPPORT)

find_package(Perl)
if(NOT PERL_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Cannot build test suites without Perl")
endif()
```

I have perl installed and running at /usr/bin/perl of my host computer. I dont know if it's some cmake config or yocto issue.

mbedcrypto recipe

```
DESCRIPTION = "Simple helloworld application"
SECTION = "examples"
DEPENDS = ""
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=302d50a6369f5f22efdb674db908167a"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "06dd48905c236f7939d03b09bcf7f1a2"


SRC_URI = "https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-crypto/archive/mbedcrypto-${PV}.tar.gz"

S = "${WORKDIR}/mbed-crypto-mbedcrypto-${PV}"

inherit cmake pkgconfig
```

Comment: Hard to tell without more details. Can you point to the line in your CMake file where this error is generated? Or any line referencing perl? I have used CMake in the past but never with perl. If your CMake file is small you can post it, or if not then post the relevant section.

Comment: I have edited the question with some info

Comment: Looks like the python interpreter can't be found either. CMake has debugging options. Can you run it with them. Look at the documentation.  Maybe `--trace` would help, or `--debug-output`.

Comment: what does your recipe look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recipe is missing *build-time* dependency for Perl and Python. These dependencies are specified by [DEPENDS variable](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-DEPENDS).

If you need native variant of Perl to build tests, specify (edit: according to the comment, it didn't help):

```
DEPENDS = "perl-native"
```

You can also use [perlnative class (see doc for the difference)](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-classes-perlnative):

```
inherit perlnative
```

BTW there are also *runtime* dependencies (see [RDEPENDS variable)](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-RDEPENDS).

Comment: Hi Tomas...  Tried first with DEPENDS = "perl-native" but it wasn't working...not sure why... but adding "inherit perlnative" instead to the recipe solved the problem.